# json в array на php

Tags: php, json

получаю при помощи file_get_contents() вот такое дело

```
{"tunnels":[{"name":"command_line","uri":"/api/tunnels/command_line","public_url":"https://r923q2es.ngrok.io","proto":"https", ..
```

Как мне взять отсюда public_url?

Comment: это не xml а json

Comment: да точно , этож json

Comment: круть! file_get_contents() сразу в json берёт (а в браузере xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Декодируйте json в *(к примеру)* объект, и обращайтесь к его свойствам следующим образом:

```
$json = '{"tunnels":[{"name":"command_line","uri":"/api/tunnels/command_line","public_url":"https://r923q2es.ngrok.io","proto":"https"}]}';

$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->tunnels[0]->public_url; // https://r923q2es.ngrok.io
```

Если нужно получить значений больше одного, тогда пройдитесь циклом по объекту:

```
foreach ($obj->tunnels as $item) {
    echo $item->public_url . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Да, точно, 
$obj['tunnels'][0]['public_url']; работает

Comment: я [0] пропускал

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу Эдуарда - чтобы json_decode возвращал массив а не объект добавьте вторым параметром true

```
$tunnels = json_decode($json, true);
echo $tunnels[0]['public_url'];
```

И да, это не XML )